# RAILS_ENV is "test" for resque but not for unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, resque

When I run my application in my development environment, resque is running in the "test" environment but the unicorns are running under "development".

I've done some debugging and discovered that `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` is getting set to "test" when in `config/application.rb` when `require 'rails/all'` is called, but only for the resque processes, not for the unicorn processes.  I'm not sure what would be different between these two that would cause this.

Here are the versions I'm using: (Rails 4.0.0, Ruby 2.0.0-p195, resque 1.25.2, resque-pool 0.3.0)

Here is my `Procfile.dev`:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c config/unicorn.rb
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=10 VVERBOSE=1 bundle exec resque-pool --config config/resque-pool/development.yml
```

I updated my `config/application.rb` to include:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

puts "before rails/all: #{ENV['RAILS_ENV'].inspect}"
require 'rails/all'
puts "after rails/all: #{ENV['RAILS_ENV'].inspect}"
```

Then when running the app:

```
$ rvmsudo foreman start -p 80 -f Procfile.dev
18:01:56 web.1    | started with pid 11211
18:01:56 resque.1 | started with pid 11212
18:01:57 web.1    | I, [2014-05-24T18:01:57.865524 #11211]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
18:01:57 web.1    | before rails/all: nil
18:01:57 resque.1 | resque-pool-manager[flow][11212]: Resque Pool running in development environment
18:01:58 resque.1 | before rails/all: nil
18:01:58 web.1    | after rails/all: nil
18:01:58 resque.1 | after rails/all: "test"
```

As you can see, for `web.1` RAILS_ENV is undefined before and after calling `require 'rails/all'` but in `resque.1` it gets set to "test".

This causes problems later because the resque workers are connecting to a different database from the web workers.

I can hack this to work by adding `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'` before `require 'rails/all'` but I haven't run into this in other apps, so I'm concerned there's a larger configuration issue I'm missing.

I've also done a search for "RAILS_ENV" throughout my application and only found one instance where it's being set to test (in `test/test_helper.rb`), but I've changed this to set it to "development" and didn't resolve the issue because it's obviously getting set much earlier when rails is loading.

Comment: Is the code base viewable?  Have a GitHub URL perhaps?

Comment: No it's not.  It's mostly a stock app at this point, however, and this issue is happening before any of my application code runs. I can provide my Gemfile if you're trying to repro.

Comment: Are you setting RACK_ENV to test at any point? The rails environment is set in the precedence of `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || ENV['RACK_ENV'] || "development"`

Comment: No, I'm not setting RACK_ENV anywhere.